# In MLA, how is the first page heading formatted with co-authors?

Tags: mla, heading

Typically, you structure MLA:

> John Smith
> Professor Adam Houser
> English 105
> 3 December 2015

(Page Header: "Smith 1")

How would you arrange this for a co-written paper? I could not find any clear answers online. My assumption is that it goes like this:

> John Smith
> Kayla Ellsworth
> Professor Adam Houser
> 3 December 2015

(Page Header: "Smith & Ellsworth 1")

Is this how it works? I need help with the proper formatting.

Answer (score 2):

In the current MLA style guide, there is no guidance for multiple authors on the title page. I would suggest following a similar format to the citation style, like this:

> John Smith and Kayla Ellsworth
>   Professor Adam Houser
>   3 December 2015

And also using the same style as citations in the header:

> Smith and Ellsworth 1

But this is just a suggestion.